# Convert column values to date in R

Tags: r, excel, dataframe, date, dplyr

The following topics have been read and applied with no success

[convert specified columns to dates in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17052077/convert-specified-columns-to-dates-in-r)
[R convert character vector values to Date values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33719792/r-convert-character-vector-values-to-date-values)

I have a column of values named `dates`that for some reason I can't convert to actual dates using `as.Dates`. It is in a dataframe named `general`.

I have tried to extract it to another object, but all I got was a list of values

```
[[1]]
 [1] NA           "43897"      NA           "44004"      "23/05/2020" "25/06/2020" "25/06/2020"
 [8] "43837"      "43989"      "43868"      "43989"      "18/07/2020" NA           "23/06/2020"
[15] "30/06/2020" "21/07/2020" "31/07/2020" "24/06/2020" "28/06/2020" "17/06/2020" "43989"     
[22] "16/06/2020" NA           "43896"      "23/06/2020" "44018"      "31/05/2020" "28/05/2020"
[29] "44081"      "25/06/2020" NA           NA           "27/06/2020" "43926"      "17/05/2020"
[36] NA           "43956"      "20/06/2020" "24/04/2020" "24/03/2020" "22/02/2020" NA          
[43] NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA          
[50] NA           NA           NA           "44030"      "43837"      "18/07/2020"
```

I have tried

`as.Date(general$dates,"%Y-%m-%d")`

which returns

```
 [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[32] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

or even

```
lapply(general$dates,as.Date,origin = "1970-01-01")
Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

Any light would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How about as.Date(general$dates,"%d/%m/%Y")?

Comment: @LocoGris I have tried it, but it ends up transforming some observations into NAs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As there are two formats, we could use `grep` to create an index and do this separately.

```
# // create an index to separate the numeric only dates
i1 <- grepl('^\\d+$', dates)
dates1 <- as.Date(rep(NA, length(dates)))
# // specify the origin - seems like 1899 instead of 1970
dates1[i1] <-  as.Date(as.numeric(dates[i1]), origin = '1899-12-31')
# // assign the other dates as well with the format
dates1[!i1] <- as.Date(dates[!i1], "%d/%m/%Y")
dates1
[1] NA           "2020-03-08" NA           "2020-06-23" "2020-05-23" "2020-06-25" "2020-06-25" "2020-01-08" "2020-06-08"
[10] "2020-02-08" "2020-06-08" "2020-07-18" NA           "2020-06-23" "2020-06-30" "2020-07-21" "2020-07-31" "2020-06-24"
[19] "2020-06-28" "2020-06-17" "2020-06-08" "2020-06-16" NA           "2020-03-07" "2020-06-23" "2020-07-07" "2020-05-31"
[28] "2020-05-28" "2020-09-08" "2020-06-25" NA           NA           "2020-06-27" "2020-04-06" "2020-05-17" NA          
[37] "2020-05-06" "2020-06-20" "2020-04-24" "2020-03-24" "2020-02-22" NA           NA           NA           NA          
[46] NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           "2020-07-19" "2020-01-08"
[55] "2020-07-18"
```

---

Or if we use `lubridate`, with `dplyr`, it is more easier

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
coalesce(as_date(as.numeric(dates)), dmy(dates))
```

The `origin` in `as_date` should be changed accordingly

#### data

```
dates <- c(NA, "43897", NA, "44004", "23/05/2020", "25/06/2020", "25/06/2020", 
"43837", "43989", "43868", "43989", "18/07/2020", NA, "23/06/2020", 
"30/06/2020", "21/07/2020", "31/07/2020", "24/06/2020", "28/06/2020", 
"17/06/2020", "43989", "16/06/2020", NA, "43896", "23/06/2020", 
"44018", "31/05/2020", "28/05/2020", "44081", "25/06/2020", NA, 
NA, "27/06/2020", "43926", "17/05/2020", NA, "43956", "20/06/2020", 
"24/04/2020", "24/03/2020", "22/02/2020", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "44030", "43837", "18/07/2020")
```

Comment: Hi. It worked partially. Some values have behaved weirdly, as it follows:

```[1] NA           "2090-03-09" NA           "2090-06-24" "2020-05-23" "2020-06-25" "2020-06-25"
 [8] "2090-01-08" "2090-06-09" "2090-02-08" "2090-06-09" "2020-07-18" NA  ```

It did change into a date format, but weirdly, to 2090 instead of 2020. Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Hi. By using the ```grep``` method it worked perfectly. By using ```lubridate```, it didn't and some values have behaved weirdly, transforming the year to 2090 instead of 2020. Any idea on why that happens?

Comment: @dairelix yes, as I mentioned in the post, the `origin` is by default `'1970-01-01'`   You could specify that `origin` as in `as.Date` with the custom one